# Get "getText()" from child of type TextView within a custom ViewGroup at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, viewgroup

How is it possible to get "getText()" from child of type TextView within a custom ViewGroup at runtime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
((TextView)viewGroup.getChildAt(indexOfTextView)).getText();
```

Where `viewGroup` is the ViewGroup containing the TextView and `indexOfTextView` is the index in that group.

Make sure to cast the view returned from the getChildAt method to A TextView before calling getText().

ViewGroup Docs for getChildAt()
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

Comment: Great! I removed "viewGroup." and its working. Thanks